# Python3 - Problems with converting between different number systems

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, binary, converters

I am writing a simple program to switch a number between base 10, 2, 8 and 16. However I'm having problems with multiple conversions or converting back to denary. Here is the code i'm using

```
#! python3

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

CurrentSystem = 'd'

def clearEnt():
    ent.delete(0, last = None)

def baseConverter(value,base):
    try:
        if base == 2:
            clearEnt()
            ent.insert(0, bin(value))
            CurrentSystem = 'b'
        if base == 8:
            clearEnt()
            ent.insert(0, oct(value))
            CurrentSystem == 'o'
        if base == 16:
            clearEnt()
            ent.insert(0, hex(value))
            CurrentSystem == 'h'
        if base == 10:
            if CurrentSystem == 'b':
                clearEnt()
                ent.insert(0, int(value, 2))
            if CurrentSystem == 'o':
                clearEnt()
                ent.insert(0, int(value, 8))
            if CurrentSystem == 'h':
                clearEnt()
                ent.insert(0, int(value, 16))
    except ValueError:
        clearEnt()
        ent.insert(0, 'ERROR')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Number Converter')

ent = ttk.Entry()
ent.grid (row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2, padx = 5)

button1 = ttk.Button(root, text = "Den")
button2 = ttk.Button(root, text = "Bin", command = lambda:baseConverter(int(ent.get()), 2))
button3 = ttk.Button(root, text = "Oct", command = lambda:baseConverter(ent.get(), 8))
button4 = ttk.Button(root, text = "Hex", command = lambda:baseConverter(ent.get(), 16))

button1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
button2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
button3.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
button4.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, the idea is that the number in the ent TK entry box changes based on the button press. So far it will change from den to one other system and then refuse to change or work again. I would appreciate any help or advice on this. Thank you

Comment: Make your code modular. Forget about tkinter completely for a while and just concentrate on getting the conversion function or functions right. Then -- call them as appropriate in your event handlers. What problems are you having with the conversion itself?

Comment: When running it with python3.4 there are constantly error messages like: ent.insert(0, oct(value))
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. Most likely the problem is that the values are represented as strings and your oct/hex commands fail.

Comment: To expand on my last comment, a good strategy would be to write a Python function `changeBase(s,a,b)` which would take a *string* `s`, an int `a` which represents the current base of `s` and an int `b` which represents the target base, and which returns a string representing the number in the target base. Get this so that it runs flawlessly in the shell (perhaps write a test script for it that tests all 4x4 = 16 valid cases) and then worry about how to wire it into tkinter

Answer (score 0):

Note the lack of symmetry in the 4 lines:

```
button1 = ttk.Button(root, text = "Den")
button2 = ttk.Button(root, text = "Bin", command = lambda:baseConverter(int(ent.get()), 2))
button3 = ttk.Button(root, text = "Oct", command = lambda:baseConverter(ent.get(), 8))
button4 = ttk.Button(root, text = "Hex", command = lambda:baseConverter(ent.get(), 16))
```

In the first one, there is no command, the second one makes sense (but still has a problem) and the third and fourth lack the call to `int` that is in the fourth. Why not make all 4 lines look more like the second line? Also -- note that if `int()` takes an optional argument for the base. Perhaps you want to do something with that argument, something that involves `CurrentSystem`. Note that for that purpose it might be better for `CurrentSystem` to hold an int such as 2,8,10, or 16 rather than a string.

Finally, note that for display purposes you might want to display something which looks like `100101` rather than `0b100101`. For that you can use a slice operator: if `s = '0b100101'` then `s[2:] = '100101'`

Comment: I completely missed the difference between button 2 and 3/4. I made this change. I honestly have no idea what to do for the first button though

Comment: You are probably confused by the absence of a base-10 version of `bin, oct, hex`. Just use `str()` in that case. Base-10 is the *default* string representation of an `int`. You don't need to do anything special. Also, note that `int("123",10) = 123)`. Giving the base (10) isn't necessary -- but it doesn't harm anything either.

Comment: What if I convert to one system and want it to go back to den? I'm going to add radiobuttons to show the current number system used by the value in the entry

Comment: All transformations should be from string to int and then back to string. Use the int as the common denominator. Going from base 8 to base 10 shouldn't be any harder than going from base 8 to base 16.

Comment: https://ghostbin.com/paste/wcjjz This is how the code looks now. I tick den and press the oct button. Instead, i'm getting this error http://prntscr.com/az54hc

Comment: I really don't see why you are trying to treat base 10 in a fundamentally different way from other bases. Also -- you seem to be vacillating between using things like `"Bin"` or `"b"` for `CurrentSystem`. You should be consistent, though neither is a very good choice compared to just using the integer `2` -- which could be fed directly into `int()` as the base argument.

Comment: I know I need to clean up the b/bin thing. I'll do so in the next pass through. What do you mean as treating base 10 differently? What do you think I should do for it then?

Comment: Your code from button 1 is still fundamentally different from the other 3 buttons. I think that those buttons should each take the string in the box, interpret it according to the current base (using the function `int()` with the appropriate base) and then display it according to the button which was pressed.

Comment: This is my code [now](https://ghostbin.com/paste/c3bqh). When i enter a den value and try to convert to binary I get an error. I tried to then convert a binary value to denary (101010b = 42d), I instead got the same binary string copied and appended to the ent again

Comment: @AshIsbitt that code doesn't work at all. You are taking input strings and not converting them to integers but then feeding them to functions like `hex()` which are expecting integers.

Comment: adding value = int(value) above the IF statement in the function makes den > anything work. If i enter a number in another base and press the Den button, the number is just appended to the entrybox. IE if i have 101 in the box and press Den, the textbox will read 101101.

EDIT: Thats what I wanted the radiobuttons there for, but I can't figure out how to use them, despite the documentation. I cant get one to be selected by default either...

Answer (score 0):

This consists of two parts, going from a string to an integer and back again. So it's a good idea to create a function for each unit of functionality.

Convert a string to an integer.

```
int('100', 8) == 8**2  # second argument is the base
```

Convert an integer to a string.

```
def int_to_str(number, base):
    assert isinstance(number, int)
    char = {2:'b', 8:'o', 10:'d', 16:'x'}[base]
    return '{0:{1}}'.format(number, char)

int_to_str(8**2, 8) == '100'
```

Then use these functions in your TK code. Something like this:

```
button1 = ttk.Button(root, text="Dec", command=lambda:int(ent.get(), 10))
button2 = ttk.Button(root, text="Bin", command=lambda:int(ent.get(), 2))
button3 = ttk.Button(root, text="Oct", command=lambda:int(ent.get(), 8))
button4 = ttk.Button(root, text="Hex", command=lambda:int(ent.get(), 16))
```

Comment: What you are saying is that I use the first line as the lambdas and then put them throuh the function before printing?

Comment: What you get from the entry box is a string. To convert this to an integer you need to know the base. Your code indicates the users tells you the base by pressing the corresponding button. Thus, you use the `int` function, passing it both the input string and the base, to get the actual integer the users wants.
To get the base for outputting the number, you need an third piece of information from e.g. a TK Radiobutton. Then you call the `int_to_str` with the integer to convert (result from `int` before) and the output base, and show the resulting string to the user.